# meteor 0.7.0 Error: A method named 'login' is already defined

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

just updated to the latest meteor (0.7.0) ran mrt update too. now it crashes miserably. Ideas?

Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

```
I20131219-18:33:43.120(0)? ShareJS: Using Meteor's mongo for persistence.
W20131219-18:33:44.903(0)? (STDERR) /home/morango/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20131219-18:33:44.904(0)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20131219-18:33:44.904(0)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20131219-18:33:44.934(0)? (STDERR) Error: A method named 'login' is already defined
W20131219-18:33:44.935(0)? (STDERR)     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1210
W20131219-18:33:44.936(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:87)
W20131219-18:33:44.936(0)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.methods (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1208)
W20131219-18:33:44.936(0)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/Spy/lib/server/manager.js:57)
W20131219-18:33:44.936(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/morango/code/ficshelf/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:159:61
W20131219-18:33:44.936(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20131219-18:33:44.938(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/morango/.meteor/tools/ec9f953f89/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20131219-18:33:44.939(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/morango/code/ficshelf/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:159:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 0):

silly me. mrt package Spy was causing the problem.